# Bootstrap 3 in ES6 wont work

Tags: ecmascript-6, bootstrap-sass, es6-module-loader

Im trying to use bootrap 3 in es6 by importing it like i do with jquery. But i keep getting this error that i cant figure out. Any solutions?

code:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import jQuery from 'jquery';
import bootstrap from "bootstrap-sass";

window.$ = $;
window.jQuery = jQuery;


$(() => {
    console.log('hola!');
});
```

This is the error im getting:

'Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery'

both jquery and bootstrap-sass are installed with NPM.